# How to remove empty rows between row data in excel using POI HSSF Library in Java

Tags: java, excel

I need help to remove empty row between created list of records. i already code to remove empty rows however it able removed the first empty row only. here is the code i done:

```
private static void writeExcelFile(String[] keyValue, String fileName, String contents,
        ArrayList<String> listProperties, ArrayList<String> listPropertiesDescription,
        ArrayList<String> listPropertiesFileName) {

    int rownum = 2;
    HSSFSheet firstSheet;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;

    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    firstSheet = workbook.createSheet("Resourcebundle");
    Row headerRow = firstSheet.createRow((short) 1);
    headerRow.setHeightInPoints(30);

    headerRow.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Properties Name");
    headerRow.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Properties Description");
    headerRow.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Properties File Name");

    System.out.println("listPropertiesDescription ::  " + listPropertiesDescription.size());
    System.out.println("listPropertiesFileName ::  " + listPropertiesFileName.size());
    System.out.println("listProperties all list ::  " + listProperties.toString());
    System.out.println("listPropertiesDescription all list ::  "
            + listPropertiesDescription.toString());

    int indexProperties = 0;
    for (int i = rownum; i < listProperties.size(); i++) {

        //            Row row = firstSheet.getRow(i + 1);
        Row row = firstSheet.getRow(i);
        //            System.out.println("row ::  " + row);

        if (row == null) {
            //                row = firstSheet.createRow(i + 1);
            row = firstSheet.createRow(i);

        }

        System.out.println("check index :: " + indexProperties);

        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
            System.out.println("cell ::  " + cell);

            if (cell == null) {
                row.createCell(j).setCellValue(
                        listProperties.get(indexProperties + 1).toString().trim());
                row.createCell(j + 1).setCellValue(
                        listPropertiesDescription.get(indexProperties + 1).toString().trim());
                row.createCell(j + 2).setCellValue(
                        listPropertiesFileName.get(indexProperties + 1).toString().trim());
            }
            j++;
        }
        indexProperties++;

        System.out.println("check index below ::  " + indexProperties);

        i++;

    }

    int lastRowCount = firstSheet.getLastRowNum();

    for (int i = rownum; i < lastRowCount; i++) {
        HSSFRow row = firstSheet.getRow(i);

        if (row == null) {
            removeRow(firstSheet, i);
            //                firstSheet.shiftRows(i + 1, lastRowCount, -1);
            //                i--; // Since you move row at i+1 to i 
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("OnlineHelp Master Excel.xls");

        //if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        String fileRB = outputLocation.concat("\\" + file);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileRB));
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void removeRow(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum) {
        sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
    }
    if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
        HSSFRow removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (removingRow != null) {
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
        }
    }
}
```

here i attach also result from the above code:

[image]

the results:

```
Row | Result
1   | result a
2   | (empty row)
3   | result b
4   | (empty row)
5   | result b
6   | (empty row)
```

it only able to removed empty row below result a, the rest still there.

really need help on this. thanks!

ema

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a pretty old thread but ran into this problem this morning.  Was not expecting HSSF library to get empty lines. So posting this answer so other members than run into it will have an answer.

Here's my solution - basically copy/paste of parts found around.

```
        HSSFSheet sheet = new HSSFWorkbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(content)).getSheetAt(0);
        int headerRowIndex = sheet.getFirstRowNum();

        List<String> columnNames = getColumnNames(sheet);
        List<Map<String, String>> sheetData = new ArrayList<>();

        sheet.forEach(row -> {
            if (row.getRowNum() != headerRowIndex && !isRowEmpty(row)) {
                sheetData.add(getRowData(row, columnNames));
            }
        });
```

... And the method:

```
        private boolean isRowEmpty(Row row) {
           for (int cellIndex = row.getFirstCellNum(); cellIndex < row.getLastCellNum(); cellIndex++) {
               Cell cell = row.getCell(cellIndex);
               if (cell != null && cell.getCellTypeEnum() != CellType.BLANK) {
                   return false;
               }
           }
           return true;
        }
```

My test file had previously 6 empty rows.  They are all gone now :) Enjoy!